# How do I Deserialize Json data from WebClient or Url and display it on standard output in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have have a json url that i would like to extract data from, I am just new to doing this. What I have attempted to do is to copy the the json data and get it to a class. Now I want to use the json data from the url to put it into variables created on that class and display it on standard output.

Here is what I have done:

[image]

Comment: Please do always post your code as text and not as image

Comment: Try to add some code or fiddle always

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the ToString method on the Current_Observation object to output object properties to the console.